# Integration of Angularjs route into Zend framework

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework, angularjs-routing

Below is my angularjs route code:

```
  'use strict';

/* App Module */

var sApp = angular.module('sApp', [
'ngRoute',
'sAppControllers',
'sAppServices','swipeLi'
]);

sApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.
  when('/discover', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home-page.html',
    controller: 'ProfileListCtrl',
}).
  when('/discover/:username', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/profile-detail.html',
    controller: 'ProfileDetailCtrl'
  }).
when('/discover/details/see-all',{
    templateUrl: 'see-all.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
}).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/discover'
  });
}]);
```

I wish to integrate this code in Zend framework. I have set the layout for my page in Zend. but when I try to call the view I get the error that it is unable to find the file as defined in my angular route.

My view code:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

The error I am getting is 'partials/home-page.html' file not found I have placed the partials folder and all the files in the same folder where I have the view code.